# Bash using optional parameters

Tags: bash, parameters, shift

I am trying to create a function that will take in `$PASS`, `$USER`, and `$COMMAND` as inputs the `$USER` and `$PASS` are optional, meaning it will use default username and passwords if non was supplied as parameters. Here is my function

```
function exec_ssh_command() {
    local PASS=${1:-${ROOT_PW}};    # use argument supplied or default root pw
    local USER=${2:-${ROOT_USER}};
    shift 2
    local COMMAND=$@

    echo "Executing command: ${COMMAND}..."

    sshpass -p ${PASS} ssh ${USER}@${ADDRESS} ${COMMAND}
}
```

If this is run without `$1` and `$2` arguments it breaks the function, so the output would be something like `sshpass -p ls -ltr ssh {USER}@{ADDRESS} ls -ltr` if my `$COMMAND` is `ls -ltr`

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getopts` to parse positional parameters as below:

```
exec_ssh_command() {
    local OPTIND=0
    local OPTARG OPTION
    local pass=${DEFAULT_PASS} user=${DEFAULT_USER}
    while getopts "u:p:" OPTION; do
        case "$OPTION" in
        u) user=$OPTARG;;
        p) pass=$OPTARG;;
        esac
    done

    sshpass -p "$pass" ssh "${user}@${ADDRESS}" "${@:OPTIND}"
}

Sample usages:

exec_ssh_command -u my_user -p my_password ls -ltr
exec_ssh_command -p my_password ls -ltr
exec_ssh_command -p my_password ls -ltr
exec_ssh_command ls -ltr
```

Explanation:
See `help getopts` on a bash prompt for the complete info. (Any explanation I would have added here would have been just a snippet from the same output.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide at least two arguments, the `shift 2` can fail because there are not enough arguments to shift. Try testing them before:

```
if [[ -n "$1" ]] ; then
    PASS="$1"
    shift
else
    PASS="$ROOT_PW"
fi
if [[ -n "$1" ]] ; then
    USER="$1"
    shift
else
    USER="$ROOT_USER"
fi
COMMAND=$@
...
```

Comment: I was hoping it would use the default if none was supplied

Comment: @honeybadger_execute that's what it does, but the `shift` should be done only when the parameter is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the convention that the function is to be called: `exec_ssh_command [[user] password] command`, you could implement it like:

```
exec_ssh_command() {
    local pass user
    case $# in
    2) pass=${ROOT_PW}; user="$1"; shift 1;;
    1) pass=${ROOT_PW}; user=${ROOT_USER};;
    *) pass="$1"; user="$2"; shift 2;; 
    esac
    sshpass -p "$pass" ssh "${user}@${ADDRESS?}" "$@"
}
```

or (basically the same thing, just a stylistic difference):

```
exec_ssh_command() {
    local pass user
    case $# in
    2) user="$1"; shift 1;;
    1) ;;
    *) pass="$1"; user="$2"; shift 2;;
    esac
    sshpass -p "${pass:-$ROOT_PW}" ssh "${user:-$ROOT_USER}@${ADDRESS?}" "$@"
}
```

Comment: `exec_ssh_command root ls -l` will interpret `root` as `user`, `ls` as `password`.
I would suggest using `-u`, `-p` and `getopts`. (Unless OP is planning to use `exec_ssh_command root "ls -l"`, which also does not feel right. Even your answer is using "$@" as the command; not "$1")